# Having trouble positioning a navigation bar with a top margin without creating a vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, margin

Hey all and thanks for taking the time to read,

I'm trying to create my online portfilo. I would like the navigation bar to have about a 10% margin from the top of the page. However, when I try a vertical scroll bar is added to the browser. I feel like this is something to do with setting the body, html to 100%. However, I'm not sure why the navigation bar isn't just applying that top margin to the content div its in instead of the whole page. All the other elements in the content div work fine.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Below is my Code.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body, html{
 background-color: #000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 
}
#content{
 background-color: #FF0004;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-right: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 
}
#nav_bar{
 margin-top: 10%;
 background-color:#DCB017;
 width:100%;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #000;
}
#navigation{
 margin-left:5%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:#292929;
 width:80%;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: "BebasNeue", sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:85%;
}
#navigation a{
 border-width:0px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#intro{
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 color: #FFF;
}
.lower{
 font-size:240%;
}
.upper{
 font-size:300%;
}
#aboutme_tab{
 width:100%;
 background-color: #149840;
}
h1{
 
 color: #FFF;
 bottom:0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfilo</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
 <div id = "content">
     <div id = "test">
        </div>
        <div id = "nav_bar">
            <div id = "navigation">
                <table width="100%" height = "60" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">HOME</a></td>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">ABOUT</a></td>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">MY WORK</a></td>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">CONTACT</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id = "intro">
           <span class = "lower"> HI! MY NAMES </span> <span class = "upper"> <b>JAMES HOSKIN</b> </span> <span class = "lower"> AND I'M A <b>SOFTWARE DEVELOPER.</b> </span>
       </div>
         
           <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
          
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow so sorry if I have posted this incorrectly or unclearly. Please advise me if so. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I solved it, I just placed a div with a height of 10% at the top of the page. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to add the extra div you could do the following: Remove the margin from the nav_bar and instead add a padding-top of 10% to the #content div, in combination with box-sizing: border-box you will no longer get the scroll bar.

```
#content{
    background-color: #FF0004;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe collapsing margins are the reason for the behaviour you're seeing. Essentially, if you have an child element with a top margin within a parent element without a top border or any top padding, the child's margin will be applied to the parent element.

Notice how you don't see any red in the below snippet.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        Hello!
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How I'd approach the problem is to remove the top-margin on the navbar completely and add 10% padding-top to the body. You can use box-sizing: border-box to make the height declaration of 100% inclusive of padding:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body, html{
 background-color: #000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
}
body {
  padding-top: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content{
 background-color: #FF0004;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-right: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 
}
#nav_bar{
 background-color:#DCB017;
 width:100%;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #000;
}
#navigation{
 margin-left:5%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:#292929;
 width:80%;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: "BebasNeue", sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:85%;
}
#navigation a{
 border-width:0px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#intro{
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 color: #FFF;
}
.lower{
 font-size:240%;
}
.upper{
 font-size:300%;
}
#aboutme_tab{
 width:100%;
 background-color: #149840;
}
h1{
 
 color: #FFF;
 bottom:0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfilo</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
 <div id = "content">
     <div id = "test">
        </div>
        <div id = "nav_bar">
            <div id = "navigation">
                <table width="100%" height = "60" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">HOME</a></td>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">ABOUT</a></td>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">MY WORK</a></td>
              <td width="25%"><a href="url">CONTACT</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id = "intro">
           <span class = "lower"> HI! MY NAMES </span> <span class = "upper"> <b>JAMES HOSKIN</b> </span> <span class = "lower"> AND I'M A <b>SOFTWARE DEVELOPER.</b> </span>
       </div>
         
           <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
          
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```